# Solution Explorer Project Context Menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way of adding other options (specifically Add Interface) to the projects right click context menu (`Right Click a project > Add > [Class, new Item, new form,...]`)?

I found one option in the customize dialog to place an 'Add Interface...' item in, but this is always disabled. I found that one under the Projects category of menu customization, so i assumed it would work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently trialing ReSharper, and that has it's own set of Create New context menu entries (which are key bindable), and these support everything I am after.

The ReSharper "Create New" dialogue is a lot faster to respond than the in built Visual Studio one too.